# Как просмотреть код метода\функции из базового модуля в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как найти код нужной функции или метода?
Предположим `.replace()`. 
Где `print(help(str.replace))` выведет мне лишь информацию о `.replace`, но не код.

При помощи **inspect** я так же не нашел ни строчки про `.replace`.

```
import inspect
import string
print(inspect.getsource(string))
```

Comment: пайчарм например, предлагает обращаться к файлам библиотек по клику

Comment: каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Buil-in модули имеют только описание,но ведь где то же должны они храниться. Соч.кл (ctrl + Q) выводит информацию о пути ко всем модулям,кроме built-in.

Comment: Гляньте исходники с гита: https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: Видимо вот тут https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3a8c562/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L10600

Comment: На гитхабе сейчас можно кликать по методам